# javac cant find referenced class

Tags: javac, gnu-make

I don't seem to be able to understand the problem. I have simple project I put together for educational purposes, but, no matter what, it won't compile. I can't figure out what I'm missing. Below is the makefile:

```
SHELL := /usr/bin/env bash
JFLAGS = -g -classpath "$(PWD)/src/tld/assignments/;$(PWD)/lib/;$(CLASSPATH)"
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = src/tld/assignments/StoreDao.java \
src/tld/assignments/Store.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean: $(RM) *.class
```

The StoreDao compiles, but the Store, which references StoreDao doesn't, and says:

```
src/tld/assignments/Store.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class StoreDao
```

I've tried the classpath with slashes and without, colons, semicolons etc. - no difference.

**Special notice**, because I know someone will certainly say this. No, I don't want / cannot use Ant or Maven. The point of this assignment is to use GNU Make. (I can do it with Ant or Maven etc, that's not a problem).

Another note, just in case, I looked into similar problems posted to SO - none of them is my case (all the rest of them turned out to be a syntax error or some kind of forgetfulness on the side of the poster, which this is not).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Quite brilliantly, even though javac ignores all conventions in path naming, it's also inconsistent on different OS'es, so, it appears that path separator character on Linux isn't a semicolon - it's a colon.

Of course, the official manual never mentions that, as users are supposed to have prerequisite knowledge before they run the program... *sigh*